# How to remove SASS debug from Brunch.io compiled CSS?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, brunch

When I compile my SCSS code in to CSS using Brunch.io it adds the following to the CSS.

```
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:[*FILE PATH REMOVED*]/reset\.scss}line{font-family:\000031}}
```

I have tried adding a "quiet" flag to the Brunch config file (as suggested here: https://github.com/brunch/sass-brunch) but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

How can I stop the compiler from adding these lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable `:debug_info` to false. Like this in config.rb:

```
debug_info = false
```

Or in brunch config file you should edit these lines:

```
config =
   plugins:
     sass:
         debug: 'comments'
```

Comment: Disabling the debug flag in to the SASS files seems to work. Now I need to find a way to do this from Brunch. (As the config file change doesn't seem to work!)

Comment: Which Brunch plugin do you use to compile sass to css? Compass Brunch or Sass Brunch?

Comment: "sass-brunch": "1.6" as shown in the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it this way in *config.rb* (just specifying `debug_info` on it's own wasn't enough).

```
sass_options = {:debug_info => false}
```

Tested with Compass 1.0.3 and Sass 3.4.25

[Useful blog](https://snugug.com/musings/debugging-sass-source-maps/)